# Остановка по ошибке во время отладки в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoint

При отладке можно поставить breakpoint как сделать так чтобы получить breakpoint по ошибке? Так чтобы в месте ошибки остановилась отладка.

Comment: Run > View Breakpoints > Java Exception Breakpoints

Comment: @etki  Спасибо получилось, но ожидал немного другого! Все таки проще через стектрейс.